# Frequent concurrent method calls in Java data-logger

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, concurrency

I'm implementing a Java Data-logger which reads, at precise intervals of time, some datas from different production machines. To avoid having one call blocking the following ones, I was thinking of making a **new thread** for every call to the parser class.

However, this would require the creation of many threads, and then to stop them, every 10 seconds (which is my reading interval). A non-concurrent approach would cause me to have many delays when the parser gets an exception (due to the possible timeouts of the IoT devices i'm using) making the next calls to be delayed.

```
while(!error){

//JDBC connections and other calls here
//Queryresult is a ResultSet that returns all the machine addresses needing to be read

    while(queryresult.next()){
                        //Parser.ParseSpeedV is the method I need to call concurrently
                        Double v = Parser.ParseSpeedV(..Params..);
                        Double s = v*queryresult.getDouble("const");
                        st = conn.createStatement();
                        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ...");
                    }
st.close();
Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

**What is the best way to achieve a concurrent method calls (to the method ParseSpeedV) without having the overhead caused by thousands of thread starting every day?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation is the perfect use case for a `Thread Pool`.  This part of Java's library that's built on top of simple `Thread`s and allows you to create a fixed-sized pool of threads and reuse them over and over:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

Any time you want to do some work you add it to the executor

```
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do some work
    }
});
```

If you call execute more than 5 times, the extra runnables are held in a queue until there's room.

Now, if you need to receive information from these runnning tasks, you need to write a class that implements Runnable and accepts some kind of object that wishes to have the information that your runnable has:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
   Consumer consumer;

   public Worker(Consumer consumer) {
       this.consumer = consumer;
   }

   @Override public void run() {
       // Do work
       value = // get value
       consumer.put(value);
   }
}
```

Now all you have to do is define a Consumer class that operates on the value (has that `put()` method, or whatever) and create your `Worker`s like this:

```
Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
Worker worker = new Worker(myConsumer);
executor.execute(worker);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i'll have a look at the documentation for this

Comment: Cool and make sure to look at the different types (for example the pool doesn't have to be fixed-sized). Also if the answer ends up solving your problem, please accept it so it is clearly visible in search results.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark it now as solved. Just one more question: How does the execute command returns the value I'm expecting? Do i need to set up something for side effects or can i simply have a return value from my calls? I guess i'll have to look at the docs for this

Comment: For this, you need to extend Runnable and have it accept an object that is to be updated.  That way when the runnable needs to return a value it can simply call a method on that object.  I'll update my answer

Comment: What you describe is the Executor service and not a ThreadPool (that's something related but different). Also there is the ScheduledExecutorService, which is especially made for repeated tasks.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use is a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). It allows you to add tasks that are repeated at a fixed rate or fixed delay. So you can i.E. add a task that fetches data from a device every 10 seconds. The Executor service then makes sure that it is run in that interval with resonably low deviation.

```
final ScheduledExecutorService myScheduledExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(16);
myScheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask, 0L, 10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: This one is interesting, what i'm wondering is: how does it deal with thread termination? Does it prevent the caller thread to end?

Comment: A Java VM is active as long as there is at least one non-demon thread active. So as long as you do not explicitly set the scheduler threads to demon-type the VM should stay alive. Depending on your use-case you might however want to have a 'main' thread waiting for user input for termination, unless it is sufficient to just kill the JVM via command line/task manager.